# How to scale tiledDrawable in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Here i'm load texture and make textureregion and TiledDrawable instances:

```
textures = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("somefile.png"));
bg_grass_region = new TextureRegion(textures, 631, 175, 116, 662);
bg_grass_tiled = new TiledDrawable(bg_grass_sprite);
```

and inside `render` method of `Screen` instance i draw it like this:

```
batch.begin();
bg_grass_tiled.draw(batch, 0, 0, bg_grass_sprite.getWidth(), bg_grass_sprite.getHeight()*3);
batch.end();
```

The problem is that `bg_grass_region` is `TextureRegion` instance, and it complitly won't to scale...

So, i have a one simple question: How to scale/resize `bg_grass_tiled` or `bg_grass_region` objects?

Comment: Maybe use TiledDrawables's other draw method? draw(Batch batch, float x, float y, float originX, float originY, float width, float height, float scaleX, float scaleY, float rotation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TiledDrawable` draws a `TextureRegion` repeatedly to fill the area, instead of stretching it. Implemented by `TransformDrawable`, however It not support scaling and rotation.

so you can't use below method of `TiledDrawable`, it throws `UnsupportedOperationException`

```
draw (Batch batch, float x, float y, float originX, float originY, float width, float height, float scaleX,float scaleY, float rotation)
```

Why don't you use draw method of `SpriteBatch` with `TextureRegion`.

```
draw (TextureRegion region, float x, float y, float originX, float originY, float width, float height,float scaleX, float scaleY, float rotation);
```